# sent my application to different account on bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i sent my rails app to someone Else's bit bucket account using git by mistake.every time i try to create a new repository and send my app it asks me for that other persons account password.how can i undo this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set correct account for you git repo, by following command:

```
 git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
```

You can see these steps in `gitbucket` help [page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+Git+and+Mercurial).

Other this which can help you is `gitcredentials` by which you is used to manage credentials 
from the user. More details for this command is [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html).

```
git config credential.https://example.com.username myusername
```